# Counter in if...else statement in R to fill vector?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix, counter

I am trying to fill a vector of length 4 using simple calculations that rely on numbers from another table. The rightmost column "nrow" is the sum of the rows in `table 4.1`. `Table6.row` is a vector representing the number of elements in a row name: 99=0, a, b, and d all =1, bd=2, abd=3. I want to fill `goalvector[1]` with the quotient of `table4.1[1, "nrow"]` and `N`. `goalvector[2]` would be filled with the quotient of the sum of `table4.1[2:4, "nrow"]` and `N`, since rows 2:4 of `table4.1` all represent single elements (a, b, and d). Below is my reproducible example:

```
table6.row <- c(0,1,1,1,2,3)
table4.1 <- matrix(data=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,1,2,1), nrow=6, ncol=5)
colnames(table4.1) <- c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "nrow") 
rownames(table4.1) <- c("99", "a", "b", "d", "bd", "abd")
```

Below is the loop with the if...else statements I'm trying to run to ultimately create the vector at the end (`goalvector`).

```
goalvector <- numeric()
n.card <- 0
P <- 1
N <- 8
for (i in ncol(table4.1)) {
  if(table6.row[i]==0) {
      n.card <- table4.1[i, "nrow"]
  } else if(table6.row[i]==table6.row[i-1]) {
      n.card <- n.card + table4.1[i, "nrow"]
  } else {
      goalvector[P] <- n.card/N
      n.card <- 0
      P <- P+1
      n.card <- table4.1[i,"nrow"]
  }
}
```

The output I want:

```
goalvector <- c(.125, .5, .25, .125)
```

Where `goalvector[1]` is equal to .125 or 1/8, the quotient of `table4.1[1,"nrow"]` and `N`. `goalvector[2]` is equal to 0.5 or 4/8, which is the sum of `table4.1[2:4, "nrow"]` over `N`, because rows 2:4 of `table4.1[,"nrow"]` all represent rows with a single element in their rowname (a, b, and d). `goalvector[3]` is equal to 0.25 or 2/8, the quotient of `table4.1[5, "nrow"]` and `N` because this is the only row representing two elements (bd).

Comment: Where is `table4`? We can only see `table4.1`

Comment: Sorry, just updated that. It should all be table4.1

Comment: can you explain how you get `.125` from the table mathematically?

Comment: Just updated the question to answer that. Sorry for the confusion, I can rewrite the entire question if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you want to sum up values in `table4.1[, "nrow"]` by values in `table6.row`. Then, divide that sum by `N`, which is 8 in this case. You can do that with the function `aggregate` in base R.

```
N <- 8
goalvector <- aggregate(x ~ y, data.frame(x = table4.1[, "nrow"], y = table6.row), sum)$x / N
goalvector
```

Output

```
[1] 0.125 0.500 0.250 0.125
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, so much simpler than what I was trying to do. That worked perfectly.